# Queryable search in nested list by nested list

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Please can anyone help me in below Linq EF
I have to similar objects

```
Class Product 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public virtual ICollection<ProductAttributes> ProductAttributes { get; set; }
}
class sc : Product { }

class ProductAttributes 
{
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public long AttributesDtlID { get; set; }
}
```

when i am trying to search in product => ProductAttributes with SC => ProductAttributes
I had created below Queryable

```
Product.Where(X => X.ProductAttributes.Any(m => sc.ProductAttributes.Any(A => m.AttributesDtlID == A.AttributesDtlID)));
```

I also tried

```
Product.Where(X => X.ProductAttributes.AsEnumerable().Any(m => sc.ProductAttributes.Any(A => m.AttributesDtlID == A.AttributesDtlID)));
```

but I got the below error

```
LINQ expression ''DbSet<Product>
.Where(p => p.IsDeleted == False)
.Where(p => (MaterializeCollectionNavigation(
    navigation: Navigation: Product.ProductAttributes,
    subquery: DbSet<ProductAttributes>
        .Where(p0 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(p, "ID") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(p, "ID") == EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(p0, "ProductID")))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Any(m => __sc_ProductAttributes_0
        .Any(A => m.AttributesDtlID == A.AttributesDtlID)))'' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to accomplish with this query?

Comment: In first look the linq query could not be translated to a database query as your error states it.

Comment: @NathanielWalser 
what i need to do that i have products contain product attributes collection and need to get products by a collection of attributes.

Comment: i want to simulate this SQL 
{ select * from Product P join ProductAttributes A on P.ID = A.ID
where A.AttributesDtlID in (1,2,3) }

Answer (score 1):

Your classes don't have ID fields and not sure what 'sc' class is for.

But, assuming:

```
Class Product 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }      <- PK
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<ProductAttributes> ProductAttributes { get; set; }
}

class ProductAttributes 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }    <- PK
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public long AttributesDtlID { get; set; }
}
```

and you want to emulate (again guessing that the join should be P.ID = A.ProductID):

```
select * from Product P join ProductAttributes A on P.ID = A.ProductID where A.AttributesDtlID in (1,2,3)
```

then use:

```
List<int> attrDtlIdsFilter = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Product> products =
   Product.Where(p => 
       ProductAttributes.Where(pa => attrDtlIdsFilter.Contains(pa.AttributesDtlID))
                        .Select(pa => pa.ProductID)
                        .Contains(p.ID));
```

### UPDATE

Breakdown of query:

```
// Get a List of ProductAttributes where AttrobutesDtlID is in the List
// of attributesIds that we want to filter on
ProductAttributes.Where(pa => attrDtlIdsFilter.Contains(pa.AttributesDtlID))

// From that List, just 'select' ProductID from each ProductAttribute
.Select(pa => pa.ProductID)

// Looks to see if Product.ID is that List of ProductIDs
.Contains(p.ID)
```

Comment: Thanks, This work but can you explain why (.Any) didn't work and what is the uses of (.Select(pa => pa.ProductID)
                        .Contains(p.ID)) as when i remove it i got error

Comment: Have updated my answer with a breakdown.  Nathaniel's answer is an alternative approach of getting to the same thing.  You should have a good read up on LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Product 
{
    // primary key
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // name of product
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // relation to attributes      
    public virtual List<ProductAttribute> ProductAttributes { get; set; }
}

class ProductAttribute
{
    // primary key
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // product link
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    // this is the property which you want to test in your query (as far as I have understood)
    public long AttributesDtlID { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to get all the products now that have any link to a product with attribute id '1230' do the following:

```
DbSet<Product> Products; <-- this comes from the Entity Framework
long id = 1230;
List<Product> result;

result = Products
    .Where(p => p.ProductAttributes
        .Where(attr => attr.AttributesDtlID == id)
        .Count != 0)
    .ToList();
```

If you want the same for a given list of ids do it like this:

```
DbSet<Product> Products; <-- this comes from the Entity Framework
List<long> ids = new List<long>(){1230, 100, 20}
List<Product> result;

result = Products
    .Where(p => p.ProductAttributes
        .Where(attr =>  ids.Contains(attr.AttributesDtlID))
        .Count != 0)
    .ToList();
```